# Apps Script - splitting google form checkbox answers by commas

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

Google form checkbox question combines the selected responses into one column separated by commas. I am trying to send out a confirmation email of these responses, but the email results in a clunk format:

Register: 9:15 AM - 10:00 AM    Instructional Technology Tools & Resources (electronic lab notebooks, classroom tech, analytics, etc.), 10:10 AM - 11:00 AM   Tools for flipped or hybrid (blended) courses (learning glass, instructional design, Ted, podcast, etc.)

I'd like to replace the comma separator with `<br>` but haven't been able to figure it out.

I've tried:

```
register = e.namedValues[headers[4]].split(',');


register = e.namedValues[headers[4]];
workshops = register.replace(",", "<br>");
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thank you!

```
for (var i in headers) {
  ....... ....... 
  register = e.namedValues[headers[4]];
} 

if (e.namedValues[headers[i]].toString() != "" ) {
  textbody = ....... + register + "<br>"
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should be structured like this:

```
for (var i in headers) {
  ....... ....... 
  register = e.namedValues[headers[i]].toString();

  if (register != "" ) {
    textbody = register.replace(/,/g, "<br>");
  }
}
```

You need to perform a global replacement, after converting the array to a string.

```
function replaceCommas() {
  var headers = ['First Name', 'Timestamp', 'Last Name', 'workshops'];
  var register = {'First Name': ['Jane', 'Jon', 'Jim', 'Josie'], 'Timestamp': ['6/7/2015 20:54:13'], 'Last Name': ['Doe'], 'workshops': ['learning glass', 'instructional design', 'Ted', 'podcast']};

  //register = e.namedValues[headers[4]].split(',');

  var keyName = headers[3]; //Arrays are Zero indexed, fourth item is index 3
  Logger.log('keyName is: ' + keyName);

  var stringOfValues = register[keyName].toString();
  Logger.log('stringOfValues: ' + stringOfValues);

  var workshops = stringOfValues.replace(/,/g, "<br>");

  Logger.log('workshops: ' + workshops);
}
```

Copy the above function into your script editor, set a breakpoint on something like the first `Logger.log()` statement, and step into each line.  You can see all the values of the variables in the debug window at the bottom of the screen.

To set a breakpoint, click a line number, and a red dot will appear, that's where the code will stop.  Then click the icon of the bug.  The code will run up to the point of the breakpoint.

Here is a link to the debug documentation:

[Google Documentation - Troubleshooting](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/troubleshooting#using_the_debugger_and_breakpoints)

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! However, I am using a for-loop to loop through the headers and an if statement to convert completed answers to a string. 

for (var i in headers) {
      .......
      .......
      register = e.namedValues[headers[4]]; }

      if (e.namedValues[headers[i]].toString() != "" ) {
           textbody = ....... + register + "<br>" }

how do I incorporate the .replace() with my current code?