# Is there a way to make each option in a checkbox in Google Forms a heading in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

For example: this form contains checkboxes about T-shirt sizes.

[image]

Currently, the responses are recorded under a single heading "Shirt size". If a user submits XS and M. Google sheets will record it as "XS, M" under the "Shirt size" column.

[image]

What I would like is each option: XS, S, M, L and XL to be its own header in google sheets and each submission to show which option the user has submitted. So if someone submits XS and M, you would see something like:

[image]

I know that we can achieve sort of the same result using sections so each option creates its own header. However, for my specific needs, the number of options selected has to be restricted to a minimum of 1 and a maximum of 2. Unless there is a way to add a count of how many sections have been selected to restrict further options, I don't see this feature as the answer I'm looking for.

Comment: You always want to leave a raw form data sheet as it is. The standard for processing that form data in different ways is to do so with formulas on a separate sheet/tab. The most efficient and effective way for me or anyone else here to convey how to do that is if you will share a link to the sheet itself.

Comment: Please show what you tried and add a brief description of your search efforts as is suggested in [ask].

Comment: Related https://stackoverflow.com/q/40848250/1595451 , https://stackoverflow.com/q/65982935/1595451 ,  https://stackoverflow.com/q/29105538/1595451

Comment: @Hyun, if you are still interested in receiving help on this issue, please post a link to your sheet (or a copy of it) as I noted two days ago. If you are no longer in need of the help, please report back and let us know that.